# Alguém me explica como eu chego neste algoritmo?

Tags: java, algoritmo

```
public class Binary 
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {  
// Print binary representation of n.
      int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
      int power = 1; 
      while (power <= n/2) 
         power *= 2; 
// Now power is the largest power of 2 <= n.
      while (power > 0) 
      {  
// Cast out powers of 2 in decreasing order.
         if (n < power) { System.out.print(0);             } 
         else           { System.out.print(1); n -= power; } 
         power /= 2; 
      } 
      System.out.println(); 
   } 
}
```

Esse algoritmo recebe um argumento numérico do usuário e retorna o valor binário do mesmo.
Eu entendi o código e tudo, mas gostaria de saber como que esse algoritmo funciona,pois se eu tivesse que faze-lo não saberia como chegar/pensar nele. E se possível, quero saber qual outro algoritmo pode fazer o mesmo (passar de decimal para binário), me explicando como e porque funciona, como eu chego/penso nesse algoritmo, passo a passo.

Comment: Para entender como ele funciona, você deveria dar uma lida a respeito de números. [Binários](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_bin%C3%A1rio) são feitos na base 2, hexadecimais na base 16 e decimais na base 10. Por este motivo, neste caso, as divisões são feitas na base 2 que seria a lógica dos números binários. Lendo a respeito de como eles funcionam e são formados, provavelmente você saberia criar este algoritmo.

Comment: Eu já sei passar de decimal para binário amigo, na mão é fácil. Mas na linguagem, usando esses ciclos eu nao entendi como ele chegou nesse algoritmo, eu sei que ele finciona, mas não sei como chegar nele. Se vc olhar esse código, vai perceber que é um jeito diferente de passar decimal para binário. Isso que eu gostaria de saber, como chegar e explicar o passo a passo pq ele funciona e qual outra forma de fazer um programa semelhante mas com outro algoritmo.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, como havia citado no comentário, números binários são compostos pela base 2.

Este código em particular achei bem interessante a forma como foi feita. Não sou o melhor cara para fazer uma explicação mas tentarei.

Números binários são compostos de 1s e 0s. Cada digito de um número binário representa o "ligado" e "desligado". Cada digíto ligado, o valor somatório aumenta em 1x2^n. 
Ou seja, para um agrupamento de 4 dígitos temos o valor de, até, 15 em decimal.

> **1111** = 1x2^3 + 1x2^2 + 1x2^1 + 1x2^0 = 15

Para o valor de 1001, por exemplo:

> **1001** = 1x2^3 + 0x2^2 + 0x2^1 + 1x2^0 = 9

Note que quando o valor é 0, multiplicamos por **2^n** por 0.

Então, o que o algoritmo que você trouxe faz é o contrário.

No primeiro loop, que é o seguinte:

```
int power = 1;
while (power <= n/2) 
   power *= 2;
```

O objetivo deste loop é descobrir o maior valor de bit ativo que podemos ter. Ele já assume que todo o valor de entrada seja de, pelo menos, um digito. Ou seja, pelo menos o primeiro digito vai ser 0 ou 1, por isso o `power = 1`.

Cada passagem pelo `power *= 2` significa um digito para a esquerda.

Imagine a entrada 18 no seu programa.

```
  0001 = 1 - ignorado pois sempre teremos uma iteração.
  0010 = 2 
  0100 = 4 
  1000 = 8
 10000 = 16
100000 = 32
```

Neste caso, nós não queremos o valor de 32 porque é maior que nosso valor decimal, ou seja, se este digito virasse 1 (ou fosse ligado) seria somado 32 ao nosso montante, resultando em um valor incorreto.

A partir deste momento, sabemos que teremos que fazer 4 iterações para encontrar o valor 18.

- Checa se o valor de power > 0
- Checa o valor atual for menor que o valor do digito correspondente

  - Se for verdadeiro, quer dizer que o bit está desligado

    - Escrevemos 0
  - Se for falso, quer dizer que o bit está ligado

    - Escrevemos 1
    - Diminuímos do valor total o valor do digito correspondente
  - Divide o valor do digito correspondente por 2.
- Repete

Imagine agora o algoritmo rodando com o valor 5 (fica menor a repetição).

- Seta `power=1`
- Verifica se `power=1` é menor ou igual que `5 / 2 = 2` (lembre-se que está trabalhando com inteiros)

  - Multiplica `power=1` por 2. Temos `power=2`.
- Verifica se `power=2` é menor ou igual que `5 / 2 = 2`

  - Multiplica `power=2` por 2. Temos `power=4`.
- Verifica se `power=4` é menor ou igual que `5 / 2 = 2`
- Sai do loop

Neste caso, temos 3 iterações

- Verifica se `power=4` e maior que 0

  - Verifica se `value=5` é menor que `power=4'

    - Não é verdadeiro, neste caso, o bit não está ligado
  - Escreve 1 em tela (bit ligado)
  - Diminui de `value=5` o valor de `power=4` resultando em `value=1`.
  - Divide o valor de `power=4` por 2 resultando em `power=2` (queremos o bit da direita)
- Verifica se `power=2` e maior que 0

  - Verifica se `value=1` é menor que `power=4`

    - Escreve 0, pois este bit não está ligado
  - Divide o valor de `power=2` por 2 resultando em `power=1`
- Verifica se `power=1` e maior que 0

  - Verifica se `value=1` é menor que `power=1`

    - Não é verdadeiro, neste caso, o bit não está ligado
  - Escreve 1 em tela (bit ligado)
  - Diminui de `value=1` o valor de `power=1` resultando em `value=0`.
  - Divide o valor de `power=1` por 2 resultando em `power=0`
- Verifica se `power=0` é maior que 0
- Sai do loop

Neste caso, cada escrita resultou em **101** o que significa o número 5, como desejamos.

---

**Resumindo**

Veja que a iteração começa checando cada bit da esquerda pra direita.

Se o número é 5, através do primeiro loop descobre que serão, no máximo, 3 digitos que participam deste número, isto porque se o 4 digito for ligado resultaria num número maior que 5 (já que seu valor correspondente é 8).

Então, verifica o 3° bit que tem como valor **4**. Se ele for maior ou igual que o valor desejado, ele está ligado, ou seja, compondo o número 5. Como o número faz parte, ele é ligado (digitando 1 em tela) e diminuímos do valor **5** o valor correspondente, restando 1.

Verifica o 2° bit que tem como valor **2**. Se ele for maior ou igual que o valor desejado, ele está ligado, ou seja, compondo o número 5. Neste caso, ele é menor (já que o restante foi 1), então, o bit não está ligado e não compõe o número.

Verifica o 1° bit que tem como valor **1**. Se ele for maior ou igual que o valor desejado, ele está ligado, ou seja, compondo o número 5. Neste caso, ele é igual, ou seja, o valor correspondente a aquele bit compõe o número 5. Diminuímos do valor 1 que temos atualmente pelo valor correspondente, restando 0.

Sendo assim, temos o valor de **4** + **1** formando o número 5.

---

Se for familiarizado com C#, dê uma olhada neste código em execução.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int value = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();

    int totalBit = 1;
    int power = 1;
    while (power <= (value / 2))
    {
        power *= 2;

        Console.WriteLine($"{ power } pode fazer parte de { value }");
        totalBit++;
    }

    int total = 0;
    int bit = totalBit;
    while (power > 0)
    {
        if (value < power)
        {
            binary.Append("0");

            Console.WriteLine($"O bit { bit } ({ Math.Pow(2, bit) }) nao faz parte do numero");
        }
        else
        {
            binary.Append("1");

            total += power;
            value -= power;

            Console.WriteLine($"O bit de numero { bit } ({ Math.Pow(2, bit) }) faz parte do numero. Temos ate agora { total }");
        }

        power /= 2;
        bit--;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(binary.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Disponível no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qQN9xk) caso queira testar.

Neste caso, você tem um pouco mais de detalhes sobre o que está ocorrendo.
[[image: console com resultado[1]]

---

Aliás, claro que existem outras formas de fazer a mesma coisa e de forma mais simples mas a explicação sobre o algoritmo em específico é esta.

Provavelmente minha explicação não foi muito boa já que não é meu forte mas tentei clarear um pouco as ideias para você. Caso não seja útil para alguém, posso tentar melhorá-la ou excluí-la.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa apenas entender como funciona números binários, aí você monta seu algoritmo da melhor forma independente da linguagem, eu por exemplo programo mais em C#, fiz um exemplo assim:

```
    private static string DecimalToBinario(int numero)
    {
        string binario = ""; //VARIÁVEL DE AGREGAÇÃO QUE RECEBERÁ O BINÁRIO FINAL
        int dividendo = numero; //NESSE CASO A VARIÁVEL RECEBE UM VALOR COMOPARÂMETRO
        int resto; // NESSA ARMAZENO O RESTO QUE SERÁ AGREGADA NA VARIÁVEL BINÁRIO

        for (int i = dividendo; i > 0; i=dividendo) //LAÇO FOR QUE FAZ OS CALCULOS DE DIVISÃO POR 2
        {
            if (i == 1)                  //AQUI VERIFICO SE É
                resto = i;               //A ÚLTIMA DIVISÃO
            else                         //SE VERDADE 1 / 2 = 0,5 == 0 E 1
                resto = i % 2;           // PEGANDO O RESTO
            binario += resto.ToString(); // AGREGANDO RESTO NA VARIÁVEL BINÁRIO
            dividendo = i / 2;           // FAZENDO A DIVISÃO
        }
        return new string(binario.Reverse().ToArray());//AQUI EU INVERTO O STRING
    }
```

Criei um método que recebe um parâmetro inteiro e retorna um string que poderá ser usado da melhor forma. Trabalhei com três variáveis, daí é só analisar o código, como seu é em java, a sintaxe é praticamente a mesma do C#, dá pra entender perfeitamente.

Vou explicar baseado nessa pergunta do usuário:
Abre aspas.
"*Esse algoritmo recebe um argumento numérico do usuário e retorna o valor binário do mesmo. Eu entendi o código e tudo, mas gostaria de saber como que esse algoritmo funciona,pois se eu tivesse que faze-lo não saberia como chegar/pensar nele. E se possível, quero saber qual outro algoritmo pode fazer o mesmo (passar de decimal para binário), me explicando como e porque funciona, como eu chego/penso nesse algoritmo, passo a passo.*"

Aqui vejamos:
*Como funciona?*

1. Para saber como funciona você tem realmente saber isso uma forma
   primitiva com uma calculadora, sei lá,se você sabe o que é binário
   vc    chega na resposta.

*Como pensar/chegar nele? *

2. Esse passo depende do anterior, pois sua necessidade de resolver
   esse problema iria exigir de você esse pré-requisito. Certamente
   você faria uma pesquisa pra descobrir como converter *Decimal para
   binário*!

*E se possível, quero saber qual outro algoritmo pode fazer o mesmo (passar de decimal para binário)*

3. Essa parte pra ser feita depende das anteriores também. No meu caso
   fiz algorítimo simples que faz isso. Aqui meu amigo você usar o seu
   domínio na linguagem de programação que você está usando.

Mas veja minha lógica, no meu caso eu pensei assim:

4. preciso de um número decimal;
5. Em C# com um laço "for"Faço todas as divisões;
6. armazeno o resto agregando numa variável
7. armazeno o resultado noutra variável que será usado na próxima
   divisão
8. ao final usei a função reverse para inverter a variável do passo
   3
9. pronto o resultado será usado da melhor forma.